# What happens when you store a value in a VARCHAR, which is over the limit in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

If I setup a `varchar(255)` column will there be an error if I try to insert more than 255 characters or will it concatenate the inserted value to the first 255 characters?

Comment: Funny how some of the post are closed, I had exactly similar question and stumbled on to this question but to my surprise it is closed. Luckily there are some answers but what caused this question to not meet the guidelines, I wonder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on server configuration:

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or
>   VARCHAR column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is
>   truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of
>   nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a
>   warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.

More info here: [The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: [Citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_needed). Please provide the source of the content you're quoting.

Comment: +1 . . . @Urill, when quoting documentation it is helpful to put a link to the actual documentation as well.

Comment: @Uriil would you know by any chance know the equivalent of this is sql server